# How to load the same product after refresh the browser window in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, page-refresh, angular-local-storage

I am new to the development world ,I am working in an angular 6 application.
It is an e-commerce application .

What I want to know is ,I have 2 component from the first component I have listed  some products ,If user clicked anyone of the product the second component will get called and shown the details of the selected product ,I have completed it and working fine.

Here if the user refresh the browser window I should show the same product details after refresh .But in my case the product code is **"undefined" after refresh**(I could not call the API with the undefined code).So I used local storage to save the product code and get the it when the second component get's called .

If there is no product code is passed from first component ,I used the local storage value to call the API.

But anyone can **edit the local storage values** ,if it is get edited then the API will return some other product or error messages.

**I want to prevent it from editing or I am looking for some other logic to handle this situation safely** .

can anyone guide me to solve this .

Thanks .

code :

```
get_Product_Code(productCode: string) {

    if (productCode == "undefined") {
      this.selectedProduct = localStorage.getItem('Item_Code');
    } else {
      this.selectedProduct = productCode;
    }
    let key = 'Item_Code';
    localStorage.setItem(key, this.selectedProduct);
  }
```

Comment: BTW, it's a better idea to use `camelCase` for your functions than to use `camelCase` with underscores

Comment: can you share your both component code

Answer (score 3):

Instead of local storage you can use route based second component which will have id in the url like `/product/12132` where 12132 is the product id. When the user reloads the page you check if it's a valid project. If it is then show the project or redirect to first component or 404 page.

Comment: User can edit the product code in URL too,Then how can I show the same window with the user selected product details before .@Max

Comment: You can't stop them from editing but you can handle it gracefully when they do like taking back to home page or showing a 404 page

Comment: If your code in browser can access it then the user also can access it. There is no way to stop it. You can make it hard like putting the data in indexed db may be but it's still accessible to the user. One way i can think of is to maintain a server side session where you'll store which product user seen at last and use that when same user logs in a again

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add `typeof`

```
If(typeof productCode == "undefined"){
}
```

Comment: see currently on refresh the window I can show the same product by using local storage value.But the local storage value is editable .So I am looking for some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

use url params..

first, add a param to the route of the component:

**module:**

```
  { path: 'product/:id', component: ProductComponent },
```

**Your url:**

```
yourapp/product/789329048
```

where **789329048** is your product id

then in your product component.. read the url like:

```
 this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

            let productid = params['id'];
}
```

then pass the value productid to the api to get the details..